# How to refactor business logic to a third-party service call in a domain entity?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a domain entity, `ProjectEstimate`, that knows how to calculate its own estimated currency amount. It is was a simple calculation based on a number of fixed values available on the object itself. The `Calculate` method is called as part of the business logic and the `EstimateCost` field updated with the amount. Nothing too tough there.

However, now the calculation logic has dramatically increased in complexity and has been factored behind a third-party HTTP API call, and I am struggling to figure out how to make calls out to this API without violating the "purity" of the domain and its logic.

I am comfortable taking a double-dispatch approach to call a domain service, but even this leaves me with questions as to where I can put the logic to call the third-party API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double dispatch such as encapsulating with CalculationRequested and CalculationReceived is usually how any external calls should be encapsulated.

In event modeling, it's explained by the "Todo list" pattern: https://eventmodeling.org/posts/what-is-event-modeling/#automation

Comment: I do like this approach, but in an attempt to keep this "lite" and, frankly, not perceived as over-engineered by my fellow engineers I opted for a double-dispatched domain service that calls the `ProjectEstimate` repository. Perhaps less than ideal, but a trade-off I was willing to make in this case. p.s. the [sequence diagram format](https://eventmodeling.org/posts/what-is-event-modeling/automate_large.jpg) is amazing. I will be making use of this in future.

Answer (score 2):

> I am struggling to figure out how to make calls out to this API without violating the "purity" of the domain and its logic.

There are two common patterns that I have seen.

The part that they have in common is to create an abstraction boundary between the semantics of the API call and its implementation.  Which is to say, we're going to create a facade that looks like a function; it takes some values as an arguments and returns a value.

This pattern should feel familiar, as it is analogous to the repository pattern, where we present simple collection/cache semantics and hide behind the facade a bunch of persistence implementation detail.

Now that we have the facade, it is typically used in one of two ways.

The "easy" way is to pass the facade to the domain model as an argument.  As far as the model is concerned, it's "just" a domain service, which can be invoked or not, as necessary.

The alternative is to interact with the facade in the *application component*; reading the function arguments out of the domain model, obtaining a result from the facade, and passing that result back to the domain model.  You end up with a somewhat cleaner separation of responsibilities -- the domain model knows what to do, the application knows how to do it.

Cory Benfield's talk on [protocol libraries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cC3_jGwl_U) is a good starting point for the second approach.